# How to override default Liferay Login authentication?

Tags: liferay-6

I am using Liferay 6.1, and I want to override default Liferay Login authentication and want to set up my custom authentication.

Till now what I have done is, I have created a hook-plugin and have setup following properties in portal.properties file

```
auth.pipeline.pre=com.liferay.portal.security.auth.MyCustomAuthenticator
auth.pipeline.enable.liferay.check=false
```

where MyCustomAuthenticator is my custom authenticator class ( which implements Authenticator).

Currently, Liferay checks this custom authentication 1st, but then again it goes to Liferay itself for further Liferay authentication too.

I want to override this Liferay validation. Please help me solve this issue.
Here is my authenticator class:

```java
public class MyCustomAuthenticator implements Authenticator {  

  public int authenticateByEmailAddress(long arg0, String arg1, String arg2, Map<String, String[]> arg3, Map<String, String[]> arg4) throws AuthException {  

    System.out.println("succeeded by mail");  
    return SUCCESS;  
  }  

 public int authenticateByScreenName(long arg0, String arg1, String arg2, Map<String, String[]> arg3, Map<String, String[]> arg4) throws AuthException {  

    System.out.println("succeeded by screen name");  
    return SUCCESS;  
  }  

 public int authenticateByUserId(long arg0, long arg1, String arg2, Map<String, String[]> arg3, Map<String, String[]> arg4) throws AuthException {  

    System.out.println("succeeded by user id");  
    return SUCCESS;  
  }  

}
```

Comment: Can you post your code for your class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the following property in portal-ext.properties and then restart the server

```
auth.pipeline.enable.liferay.check=false
```

Comment: This should work. Please go through this link: http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/user-guide/-/ai/authentication-pipeline . You should also take care to handle all the other cases where an auth failes, max log attempts etc. Make sure you restart the server once you change any properties. And also try cleaning the portal's JVM, thread dump, etc from the Portal Administration in Control Panel

Answer (score 1):

Remembered in your hook project in file portal.properties

```
place auth.pipeline.pre =com.liferay.portal.security.auth.MyCustomAuthenticator 
auth.pipeline.enable.liferay.check = false
```

and also in the portal-ext-properties

Answer (score 0):

I had made a hook the same way, with these two lines in my hook portal.properties override, AND in portal-ext.properties for good measure:

```
auth.pipeline.pre=com.liferay.portal.security.auth.MyCustomAuthenticator
auth.pipeline.enable.liferay.check=false
```

However, it seemed to not want to login to Liferay even when the account already existed.  I was able to get it fully working and skip Liferay authentication altogether.  The hook overriding portal.properties is all I needed, I removed the 2 lines from portal-ext.  In your Custom Authenticator, instead of just returning SUCCESS, (com.liferay.portal.security.auth.Authenticator.SUCCESS)

You want to return SKIP_LIFERAY_CHECK .  This is the same as a SUCCESS, except making sure the authentication pipeline knows to skip the liferay check.

This should force it to work.  I believe the source code (for Liferay 6.2 ga5) does not properly take into account the "Skip Liferay Check" property, and this essentially forces it.