# Sign in to Liferay using Custom Portlet

Tags: java, liferay, portlet

I have a portlet with 2 fields - username and password.
Instead of going to the SIGN IN portlet (blue button, top right corner on Liferay page), and then signing in, I want to use my custom portlet and login to Liferay.

Here is the code I've used -

**LoginUtilCompat.java**

```
package com.compass.service;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.ClassResolverUtil;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.MethodKey;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.PortalClassInvoker;
/**
 * This class provides a compatibility layer that isolates differences between different versions of Liferay Portal.
 *
 * @author  Neil Griffin
 */
public class LoginUtilCompat {
    // Private Constants
    private static final String LOGIN_UTIL_FQCN = "com.liferay.portlet.login.util.LoginUtil";
    private static final String LOGIN_METHOD = "login";
    private static final Class <? > [] LOGIN_PARAM_TYPES = new Class <? > [] {
        HttpServletRequest.class, HttpServletResponse.class, String.class, String.class, boolean.class, String.class
    };
    public static Object invokeLogin(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse,
        String handle, String password, boolean rememberMe, String authType) throws Exception {
        Class <? > loginUtilClass = ClassResolverUtil.resolveByPortalClassLoader(LOGIN_UTIL_FQCN);
        MethodKey methodKey = new MethodKey(loginUtilClass, LOGIN_METHOD, LOGIN_PARAM_TYPES);
        return PortalClassInvoker.invoke(false, methodKey, httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse, handle, password,
            rememberMe, authType);
    }
}
```

The class where I've invoked the login method is shown below -

**Login.java**

```
public class Login extends MVCPortlet {

    @ProcessAction(name="customlogin")
    public void customlogin(ActionRequest actionRequest,
            ActionResponse actionResponse) throws IOException, PortletException {
        ThemeDisplay themeDisplay = (ThemeDisplay) actionRequest.getAttribute(WebKeys.THEME_DISPLAY);
        PortletConfig portletConfig = (PortletConfig)actionRequest.getAttribute(JavaConstants.JAVAX_PORTLET_CONFIG);
        LiferayPortletConfig liferayPortletConfig = (LiferayPortletConfig) portletConfig;

        SessionMessages.add(actionRequest, liferayPortletConfig.getPortletId() + SessionMessages.KEY_SUFFIX_HIDE_DEFAULT_ERROR_MESSAGE);

        String portletId = (String) actionRequest.getAttribute(WebKeys.PORTLET_ID);



        System.out.println("portlet id is : "+portletId);
        String login = ParamUtil.getString(actionRequest, "login");
        String password = ParamUtil.getString(actionRequest, "password");
        System.out.println("Login : "+login +"\nPassword :"+password);
        LoginUtilCompat loginutil =new LoginUtilCompat();
        HttpServletRequest request = PortalUtil.getHttpServletRequest(actionRequest);
        HttpServletResponse response = PortalUtil.getHttpServletResponse(actionResponse);

        try {
            loginutil.invokeLogin(request, response, login, password, false, null);

            System.out.println("Login invoked !!");
            //SessionMessages.add(actionRequest,"success");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            System.out.println("Error !!");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    }
```

What this code does, is that it successfully shows **Login invoked!** message when I enter my login credentials, but the SIGN IN button still remains as it is (indicating that I'm not logged into Liferay yet).

I've used the solution offered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10634437/how-to-override-default-liferay-login-authentication) but even this did not work.

[This](https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/6-1/overriding-and-adding-struts-actions) section of Liferay Documentation says that one must overrride the Login Action (which is a Strut action) in `<struts-config.xml>` located in /ROOT/WEB-INF foler of Tomcat directory. But since I am working on a portal that is soon to be pushed into production and I do not know Struts very well, I do not want to mess with a technology I don't really know about.

Comment: Have you tried creating login form using web-content?

Comment: I have created a view.jsp page (form) that has an actionURL pointing to the "customlogin" method defined in my Login.java class, if that's what you are asking.