# Liferay override login authentication not working

Tags: authentication, liferay, pipeline, authenticator

I am using liferay 6.1 CE. I want to override Login Authentication base on this post : [How to override default Liferay Login authentication?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10634437/how-to-override-default-liferay-login-authentication)

The login authentication run into my CustomAuthenticator(this class has override 3 method of Authenticator) but seem it run Liferay authentication too and return fail.

I put my portal-ext in LR-portal/TOMCAT/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/classes and auth.pipeline.enable.liferay.check=false

But seem the Liferay Authentication still running?

Any idea for help?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Any one can help me? :(

Answer (score 0):

You said you put

```
auth.pipeline.enable.liferay.check=false
```

in LR-portal/TOMCAT/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/classes/portal-ext, but you should put it to the main Liferay folder - in your case LR-portal/portal-ext.properties. You could also try to put it into hook project you created for custom authentication - into /src/resources/portal.properties file.